# error in lm.fit while using nnetar function in R

Tags: r, neural-network, forecasting

I cannot show data currently. Will submit sample data soon.

Below is the code I am using to loop through each variable and and save out the point estimates.

```
##nnetar loop####
fits <- lapply(1:ncol(tser),  function(i) nnetar(tser[,i], P=2, repeats=750, scale.inputs = T))
models <- sapply(1:ncol(tser), function(i) forecast(fits[[i]])$method)
results <- lapply(1:ncol(tser), function(i) forecast(fits[[i]], h = 12))

#Saves out Point Forecasts#
resultsmean <- lapply(1:ncol(tser), function(i) forecast(fits[[i]], h = 12)$mean)
```

Running "fits" object line, I get the error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases
```

---

dput() statement to reproduce dataset that I convert to ts() object "tser":

sampledata <- structure(list(X1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 157, 204, 166, 
                      237, 211, 161, 216, 291, 222, 234, 243, 185, 163, 150, 114, 243, 
                      96, 15, 6, 5, 19, 10, 4, 7, 2), X2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 41, 
                                                             53, 70, 45, 78, 60, 36, 53, 63, 91, 123, 101, 50, 69, 41, 32, 
                                                             102, 178, 541, 382, 417, 438, 589, 477, 387, 291), X3 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 13, 28, 34, 27, 33, 42, 38, 70, 57, 
                                                                                                                       29, 57, 44, 24, 46, 20, 48, 197, 122, 221, 291, 423, 522, 389
                                                             ), X4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 31, 34, 36, 37, 40, 83, 78, 84), X5 = c(521, 
                                                                                                                                       345, 406, 553, 561, 780, 928, 533, 433, 1121, 631, 439, 406, 
                                                                                                                                       323, 338, 486, 538, 542, 692, 428, 408, 487, 422, 750, 259, 43, 
                                                                                                                                       97, 95, 23, 35, 28, 15, 26), X6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70, 
                                                                                                                                                                           98, 90, 72, 135, 177, 97, 84, 116, 164, 184, 192, 242, 206, 198, 
                                                                                                                                                                           127, 293, 292, 776, 622, 503, 762, 764, 602, 614, 528), X7 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 41, 40, 51, 14, 32, 39, 17, 27, 23, 58, 36, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          46, 22, 42, 33, 37, 45, 348, 1314, 1150, 842, 1532, 1386, 1163, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1191, 1011), X8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 38, 44, 36, 74, 131, 170, 178, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              247), X9 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 65), X10 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0, 6), X11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2, 0, 0, 0, 0), X12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
               X13 = c(1, 5, 58, 68, 127, 177, 275, 280, 238, 475, 221, 
                       297, 295, 213, 322, 411, 460, 661, 749, 392, 565, 740, 464, 
                       624, 211, 31, 23, 13, 5, 8, 9, 4, 1), X14 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
                                                                     0, 175, 462, 468, 345, 344, 527, 452, 546, 389)), .Names = c("X1", 
                                                                                                                                  "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", 
                                                                                                                                  "X12", "X13", "X14"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 72:104)

Comment: Check the `class` of your `ts` object.

Comment: > class(tser)


[1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"

Comment: And is the `typeof` that matrix `character` or `numeric`?

Comment: > typeof(tser)
[1] "double"

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using simulated data and the same code. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @RobHyndman I am having issues getting the sample data. Will upload ASAP.

Comment: Updated with dput() statement to replicate sample data.